# Representation of $*$-automorphism on finite dimensional matrix algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras

Let $\phi$ define a $*$-automorphism from the matrix algebras $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ to $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $\phi(I) = I$. Is it true that any such map $\phi$ can be represented as $\phi(x) = U x U^{\dagger}$ (where $U$ is a suitable unitary matrix)? If not, what is the most general expression?

Comment: It is redundant to require $\phi(I)=I$.

Comment: how can this be shown?

Comment: Let $A$ be an element of $M_n$, and let $B=\phi^{-1}(A)$.  Then $\phi(I)A=\phi(I)\phi(B)=\phi(IB)=\phi(B)=A$.  Similarly, $A\phi(I)=A$, so $\phi(I)$ is an identity for $M_n$.  More generally, if $f:R\to S$ is a surjective ring homomorphism and $R$ is unital, then $f(1_R)$ is an identity for $S$, and the only difference in the proof is that you take $B\in f^{-1}(A)$ in case $f$ is not injective.

Comment: Another way to see it in the $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ case is to take a family $\{e_i\}$ of $n$ mutually orthogonal projections (which necessarily add to I, because the sum is a projection with rank $n$). Then the images also form a family $\{\phi(e_i\}$ of orthogonal projections, and the sums is a projection with trace $n$, that is $I$. 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one generalization:

> Every $*$-automorphism of the algebra of compact operators on a Hilbert space is conjugation by a unitary operator on that space.

Using the fact that the algebra of compact operators is irreducible, this can be seen as a special case of:

> Every irreducible $*$-representation of the algebra of compact operators on a Hilbert space is unitarily equivalent to the identity representation.

A proof can be found for instance in Section 1.4 of Arveson's *[An invitation to C`*` algebras](http://books.google.com/books?id=zRep59fhoGkC&lpg=PP1&dq=arveson%2520invitation&pg=PA20#v=onepage&q&f=false)*.  Another proof of the first assertion that gives more information can be found in Proposition 1.6 of Raeburn and Williams's *[Morita equivalence and continuous trace C`*`-algebras](http://books.google.com/books?id=KV_cC5uYA7EC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA5#v=onepage&q&f=false)*.

The first part is still true if you take all bounded operators instead of only the compact ones. (And these are the same thing in the finite dimensional case.)

Answer (score 6):

If $\phi$ is a $*$-automorphism then $\psi:A\mapsto\phi(\overline A)$
is a $\mathbb{C}$-automorphism. By the [Skolem-Noether](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem-Noether_theorem) theorem
every $\mathbb{C}$-automorphism of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is inner,
that is of the form $\psi(A)=UAU^{-1}$. This must commute with the
$*$-operation: $A\mapsto\overline{A}^t$. This leads to $UAU^{-1}
=\overline{U^t}^{-1}A\overline{U^t}$ for all $A$. Thus implies
that $U$ and $\overline{U^t}^{-1}$ are the same up to a constant
multiple. By multiplying $U$ by a constant we may make $U$ unitary.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to Robin Chapman's solution, I would like to state Exercise 7.8 from Rørdam's, Larsen's and Laustsen's "Introduction to the K-theory of C*-algebras":

> For every unital AF-algebra $A$ there is a short exact sequence
>   $$
> 1\to\overline{\mathrm{Inn}}(A)\to\mathrm{Aut}(A)\to\mathrm{Aut}(K_0(A))\to 1,
> $$
>   where $\overline{\mathrm{Inn}}(A)$ denotes *approximately* inner automorphisms and $\mathrm{Aut}(K_0(A))$ denotes group automorphisms preserving the unit class and the positive cone in $K_0(A)$.

If $A$ is the matrix ring, then $\mathrm{Aut}(K_0(A))$ is trivial and hence every automorphism of $A$ is approximately inner. Since $A$ is separable, every approximately inner automorphism is the pointwise limit of a sequence of inner automorphisms. And I think the finite-dimensionality of $A$ implies that the pointwise limit of a sequence of inner automorphisms is again inner.

Using the statement above, one immediately sees that, for instance, $\mathbb C\oplus\mathbb C $ possesses an automorphism which is not approximately inner.

Comment: Does anyone know how I can actually prove that the pointwise limit of a sequence of inner automorphisms of a finite-dimensional C*-algebra is again inner?

Comment: At a guess: compactness? (take a cluster point/limit of your sequence of implementing elements)

Comment: Yemon's argument works, because your sequence of unitaries is bounded in a finite dimensional space, and so it has a convergent subsequence.  On the other hand, already between the answers and the comments there are several proofs that any automorphism of a finite-dimensional C$^*$-algebra is inner. So all you need to convince yourself about is that the pointwise limit of inner automorphisms is an automorphism, and that's easy. 

Comment: @M. Argerami: Well, I don't want to use that any automorphism of a finite-dimensional C∗-algebra is inner because that's what I want to prove in the end.

Comment: I see. My bad, then. Regarding the last statement in your answer, if your $A$ is abelian, then the only inner automorphism is the identity, and then of course the only approximately inner automorphism is the identity; and a simple example of a non-inner automorphism of $\mathbb{C}\oplus\mathbb{C}$ is the ``flip'', $(a,b)\mapsto(b,a)$.

Answer (score 1):

Another proof can be obtained using that $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is singly generated (and finite-dimensional). So $M_n(\mathbb{C})=C^*(s)$ for some $s$ (the shift, for example). Now, of course, $\phi(s)$ is a generator for the image. And by Spetch's theorem, $\phi(s)$ and $s$ are unitarity equivalent (because $\phi$ is multiplicative and it preserves the trace). Then there exists a unitary $U\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ with $\phi(s)=UsU^{-1}$. If you now take any $a\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$, we have $a=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \alpha_js^j+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\beta_j(s^*)^j$, for coefficients $\alpha_j,\beta_j$, and so 
$$
\phi(a)=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \alpha_j\phi(s)^j+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\beta_j\phi(s^*)^j
$$
$$
=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \alpha_j((UsU)^{-1})^j+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\beta_j(Us^*U^{-1})^j=UaU^{-1}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Yet another proof would be to consider a system $(e_{kj})$ of matrix units in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, coming from some orthonormal basis (the canonical one, say). It is then easy to check that $(\phi(e_{kj}))$ is another system of matrix units, and so it corresponds to another orthonormal basis. The unitary implementing the change of basis is the one implementing $\phi$.